# I get more than rows i expect when use JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, join

I want to join 4 tables. I expect it  to return 4 rows while it returns 36 rows. It means the result I expect repeats 9 times.

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * 
FROM exam 
INNER JOIN studentexam ON exam.id = studentexam.examID
INNER JOIN question ON exam.id = question.examID
INNER JOIN answer ON exam.id = answer.examID
WHERE exam.id=$examID");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
if($row['type']=='singleChoice'){
    print $row['examID'].'*'.$row['studentID'].'*'.$row['questionID'].'<br>';   
}
}
```

The thing i want as result is:
99*922723627*25 --
99*922723627*26 --
99*922723627*27 --
99*922723628*25 --
But I get this 9 times. It returns all the permutations (if its the correct word in English). I have 1 exam with 3 questions and 3 candidates. The 1st candidate answered 3 question and the second did 1 and the third didn't take the exam. 
1*3*3*4 = 36

I have used JOIN many times but really confused with this. what is wrong?!

Comment: have you tried grouping by studentID?

Comment: @jim No and I dont know what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no restriction on any join between studentexam, question and answer, you will get all students for the given exam, with every record again all questions, and again all questions.

I am guessing that you are only interested in the answers given by each student to the specific questions, and not a cartesian product of all exam questions and all students that took the exam.

So your answers you want to join on

```
    answer.examid = exam.id
AND answer.studentid = student.id
AND answer.questionid = question.id
```

The whole query would be something like

```
SELECT studentexam.examId, studentexam.studentid, question.id, answer.id 
FROM studentexam 
INNER JOIN question ON exam.id = question.examID
INNER JOIN answer ON answer.examid = exam.id
                 AND answer.studentid = studentexam.studentid
                 AND answer.questionid = question.id
WHERE exam.id=$examID"
```

Note that i also left out table exam, as all you seem to want is examid that is already in studentexam

Comment: Great, IT works correctly now! I was involving it all the day. I need all the tables but I didnt know there is something like "AND" in "JOIN" clause.

Comment: You can even include simple constraints in it not related to ther tables, e.g. 'JOIN tableB on id = table A.id and tableB.type = 'foo'`:)